Python Image Blur Effect
I am working on a project which should blur the background of the image, I have used pixellib, mask r-cnn and deeplabv3 but the results are not satisfactory, the main problem I think lies in the image segmentation where the models are not able to separate the background and foreground object efficiently, can anyone tell me how can I improve the efficiency of existing models like the ones I mentioned without having to train one or any other alternative leads which can show better results for the mentioned task, I have attached my actual and expected results.
Expected Output
My Output
def run(self, image):
    """Runs inference on a single image.

    Args:
        image: A PIL.Image object, raw input image.

    Returns:
        resized_image: RGB image resized from original input image.
        seg_map: Segmentation map of resized_image.
    """
    width, height = image.size
    resize_ratio = 1.0 * self.INPUT_SIZE / max(width, height)
    target_size = (int(resize_ratio * width), int(resize_ratio * height))
    resized_image = image.convert('RGB').resize(target_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    batch_seg_map = self.sess.run(
        self.OUTPUT_TENSOR_NAME,
        feed_dict={self.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: [np.asarray(resized_image)]})
    seg_map = batch_seg_map[0]
    return resized_image, seg_map

Assuming IMAGE_NAME is defined earlier.
original_im = Image.open(IMAGE_NAME)
resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(original_im)


both of the images in the question are identical.

it looks like the question has omitted the "actual" image. please include this.

Below you can find my approach. The way it works is by taking the original image (stored in 'image.png'), extracting the foreground from the background (saving this result in 'output.png'), and then blurring the original image and superposing the extracted foreground on top of it (saving this final result in 'sick_image.png'):
from rembg import remove 
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

# Store paths
input_path = 'image.png' 
output_path = 'output.png'
sick_image_path = 'sick_image.png'

# Open the input image
input_image = Image.open(input_path)

# Removing the background from the input image
output_image = remove(input_image)

# Save the extracted car
output_image.save(output_path)

# Blur the original image
blurred_image = input_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(10))

# Overlay the extracted car onto the blurred image
blurred_image.paste(output_image, (0, 0), output_image)

# Save the resulting image
blurred_image.save(sick_image_path)

The result I get is the following:

Notice that the borders are, still, not like the reference image you linked. However, your main problem regarding contours is solved with my approach. More delicate image processing would, very likely, have to be done with more complex software and/or other ML models. Below are some links to similar questions to yours (in case you want to take a look at other answers, to contrast mine):

object (Car) Detection and segmentation or
DataSets and Background Subtraction

And some links that could be of interest to perfect the approach to blurring the background:

A paper about object detection, this allows greater control in selecting which objects to blur and which not to: https://cogcomp.seas.upenn.edu/Data/Car/
Interesting documentation regarding and OpenCV approach to object segmentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

Good luck! And may the code be with you...
